# Jump to last slide on Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm creating a Carousel with bootstrap and I'd like to create a link that jump directly to the last slide in the carousel (with *n* slides, not a fixed number). I tried to resolve the problem assigning the class `active` to the last `div` in the this way:

```
$(".last").click(function(){
    $('myCarousel div').removeClass('active'); 
    $('myCarousel div:last-child').addClass('active'); 
});
```

But, this works if I have just a carousel in my page, but if the carousels are more than one the link go to the last slide on all the carousels. How can I resolve the problem? Here is an example of the code:

```
<div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide"> 
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item active slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
   </div>
   […] other items
 </div>    
</div>
<ul>
 <a href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev"><li>Prev</li></a>
 <a href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next"><li>Next</li></a>
 <a href="#myCarousel1"><li class="last">Last</li></a>
</ul> 

<div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide"> 
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item active slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
   </div>
   […] other items
 </div>    
</div>
<ul>
 <a href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev"><li>Prev</li></a>
 <a href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next"><li>Next</li></a>
 <a href="#myCarousel2"><li class="last">Last</li></a>
</ul> 

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".last").click(function(){
  $('[id^="myCarousel"] div').removeClass("active"); 
  $('[id^="myCarousel"] div:last-child').addClass("active"); 
 });      
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use .parent('.parent-class') selector to narrow down Carousel container, this way you'll only look into last child of that parent and not all Carousels on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the carousel id to your jQuery selector like this:

```
$(".last").click(function(){
    $('#myCarousel1 div').removeClass('active'); 
    $('#myCarousel1 div:last-child').addClass('active'); 
});
```

**Edit:**

If you want the id of your carousel to be dynamic, you have to reference it somewhere. You can put an attribute on the link to the last slide and read this attribute when the link is clicked like this:

```
$('.last').click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#myCarousel' + id + ' div').removeClass('active'); 
    $('#myCarousel' + id + ' div:last-child').addClass('active');
});
```

And add a data-id to your link like this:

```
<li class="last" data-id="2">Last</li>
```

Comment: Thank you but in this way I should repeat the code for every slide... Is there a more general method that works without repeat the code, something that I can use in a way similar as the data-slide attribute?

Comment: This removes the .active class from all the div's inside #myCarousel1 and adds the active class on the last one, .last is the button class...

It will work with any number of slides

Comment: you can also use `$('#myCarousel1 div').length` instead of using a fixed index

Comment: Really sorry, I confused the terms (slide/carousel). What I meant if that I have 2 or more carousels on my page I should repeat the code for `myCarousel1, myCarousel2 ... myCarousel_n_` while I'd like to find a general way to do it...